# What is the most expressive logic such that presentations of algebraic structures "work"?

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

I feel like this is one of the best questions I've asked in a while. Hope you enjoy it.

In my opinion, one of the most important ideas in modern algebra is the idea that we can present algebraic structures by generators and relations. Explicitly:

- Start with a theory $T$ and a set $X.$
- Write $F(X)$ for the $T$-algebra freely generated by $X$.
- Let $R$ denote a binary relation on $F(X)$
- Let $R^\sim$ denote the least $T$-algebra congruence on $F(X)$ that includes $R$.
- We define that $\langle X \mid R \rangle$ is just $F(X)/R^\sim.$

Now if $T$ is an *algebraic* theory (by which I mean that it is axiomatizable purely by universally quantified equations), then we can certainly carry out all of the above steps. But really, this is far too restrictive; if $T$ is an algebraic theory, then:

- we can take Cartesian products of $T$-algebras, and
- every subset of a $T$-algebra $X$ that is closed under the operations of $T$ is itself a $T$-algebra under the induced operations.

and neither of these observations was used to ensure that presentations are well-defined. All we really needed was:

1. Free algebras exist.
2. For binary relation $R$ on $F(X)$, there is a least congruence relation on $R^\sim$ that includes $R$.
3. Congruence relations on a $T$-algebra and quotients of that algebra are essentially the same thing.

This motivates my question.

> **Question.** What is the most expressive logic such that presentations of algebraic structures "work"? Alternatively, what is the most expressive logic such that each of the above three requirements is satisfied?

Comment: May be I misunderstood you and I am far from being a specialist in universal algebra, but here are my thoughts. I think 2 is always satisfied and $R^{\sim}$ is just the intersection of all congruence relations containing $R$. What do you mean by "essentially the same" in 3? Also if you want $F(X)/R^{\sim}$ to be a $T$-algebra you need $Mod(T)$ to be closed under taking the homomorphic images. The weakest condition on the existence of $T$-free algebra of any rank I know is for $Mod(T)$ to be a replete class (contains trivial algebra and closed under subalgebras and direct products) of algebras.

Comment: @RandomJack, by 3 I basically just mean that $F(X)/R^\sim$ is indeed a $T$-algebra. Anyway, I don't think we should require full-blown closure under homomorphic images, nor closure under the taking of subalgebras and/or direct products; the whole point is to get away from these sort of "unnecessary" requirements. Does that make sense, or am I losing my mind?

Comment: If $R$ is arbitrary binary relation (or even arbitrary congruence), then "$T$ is closed under homomorphic images" is necessary for 3, since congruences of a $T$-algebra in 1-to-1 correspondence with hommomorphic images of this algebra. That's definitely makes sense, but this seems to be a really tough question in such generality. It is a very interesting idea, I will wait for answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an attempt of full answer but is too long for a comment.

While reading Gorbunov's "Algebraic theory of quasivarieties" (in Russian) I've stumbled upon the following construction. In my opinion, it is interesting and similar to yours, but instead of binary relation we have the set of formulas as the set of relations. I don't know if you are familiar with this construction or not and can it be helpful to proceed in answering exactly your question, so I will delete my answer if it is not.

This method of describing $L$-structures was proposed by Maltsev. I am not sure about the terminology below since it is my translation from Russian but the construction is clear.

Let $L$ be a signature and $\bf K$ be a class of $L$-structures, $\mathcal{A} \in \bf K$. Consider the set of variables $X$ and the set $\Delta$ of atomic $L$-formulas with variables from $X$.

We will say that $(X, \Delta)$ *defines* $\mathcal{A}$ *in* $\bf K$, if there exists $f \colon X \to A$ satisfying:

1. $f(X)$ generates $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A} \models \Delta$ in the interpretation $f$.
2. For all $\mathcal{B} \in \bf K$ and $g \colon X \to B$, if $\mathcal{B} \models \Delta$ in the interpretation $g$ then there exists a homomorphism $h \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ such that $h(f(x)) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

If $(X, \Delta)$ defines $\mathcal{A}$ with $f$ and $\mathcal{B}$ with $g$ in $\bf K$, then a homomorphism $h \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, such that $h(f(x)) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$ is an isomorphism. Hence an $L$-structure defined by $(X, \Delta)$ is unique up to isomorphism.

If this $L$-structure exists we denote it by $\mathcal{F}_{\bf K}(X, \Delta)$. $X$ is said to be *the set of generators* and $\Delta$ is said to be *the set of relations* of $\mathcal{F}_{\bf K}(X, \Delta)$.

An abstract class $\bf K$ of $L$-structures is called *a prevariety* if $\bf{K}$ $= \bf{SP}$$($$\bf{K}$$)$.

There is an existence theorem proven by Maltsev.

**Theorem:** An abstract class $\bf K$ of $L$-structures is a prevariety if and only if $\mathcal{F}_{\bf K}(X, \Delta)$ exists for every defining pair $(X, \Delta)$.

This theorem describes precisely those classes of $L$-structures in which this method of presentation by generators and relations "works". I hope this will be helpful or at least interesting for you.

Comment: I think this theorem of Maltsev totally answers the question. Observe that if $L$ has no relation symbols, then a set of atomic formulas $\Delta$ is the same thing as a binary relation $R$ on the set of $L$-terms ($t_1(\overline{x}) = t_2(\overline{y}) \in \Delta$ iff $R(t_1(\overline{x}),t_2(\overline{y}))$). Also, it's worth pointing out that if a class $\textbf{SP}(\textbf{K})$ (which is automatically closed under subalgebras and products) is also first-order axiomatizable (even [pseudo-elementary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoelementary_class)), then (continued in next comment)

Comment: it is a [quasivariety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasivariety), i.e. the set of models for a universal Horn clause (quasi-identity) theory. So if you want a logic which is contained in first-order, and you want all definitions by generators and relations to work, then universal Horn logic (the logic of quasivarieties) is the weakest such.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{SP}(\mathbf{K})$?

Comment: The class of substructures (S) of products (P) of structures in $K$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, thanks.

Comment: A very good reference for these questions: Wolfgang Wechler, Universal Algebra for Computer Scientists, Series: Monographs in Theoretical Computer Science. An EATCS Series, Vol. 25, Springer, 1992.